# Confused in regards to nesting my community and comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller, nested

I will have an option were comment model can be used for a user to post in a person profile page and community page. Currently I'm working on community and would like some direction as I'm confused.

Current error I get is ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError for my CommentsController#Create. Would like help if possible or help me point in the direction of fixing my mistake.

questions in regards to what view people are seeing comment is /communities/show

**Models**

**User**

```
has_one :profile
has_many :communities
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

**Community**

```
extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
```

**Comment**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :community
```

**Routes**

```
resources :communities do
 resources :comments
end
```

**Controllers**

**Communities**

```
def show
 @community = Community.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
 @comment = Comment.new
end
```

**Comments**

```
 before_filter :load_community
 def create
  @comment = @community.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  if @comment.save
   redirect_to :back
  else
   redirect_to "/"
  end

  # @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  # @comment.user_id = session[:user_id]

  # if @comment.save && @comment.community_id
  #   flash[:notice] = "Comment has been posted"
  # else
  #   flash[:alert] = @comment.errors.full_messages
  # end
end

private
def load_community
 @community = Community.friendly.find(params[:community_id])
end

def comment_params
 params.require(:comment).permit(:text, :user_id, :community_id, :profile_id)
end
```

**Views**

**/communities/show**

```
<%= render "profiles/index" %>
<h4><%= @community.title.capitalize! %></h4>
<%= @community.bio %>


<%= render "comments/new" %>
```

**/comments/_new**

```
<%= form_for ([@community, @comment])  do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :text, placeholder: "Enter New Comment Here ...", :cols => 50, :rows => 3, :class => 'text_field_message', :id => 'new_comment' %>
 <%= f.submit :class => 'new_comment_button' %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you everyone who helps explain where I'm making my mistake and also sorry in advance if I may need to ask what you might be requesting from me. For further questions please ask.

**UPDATE**

What I see in my console is

```
Started POST "/communities/dang/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-23 18:38:47   -0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"us8KNTLUZUdao13GK4OQId0YoUqf+CeLFIGjydnyWtI=", "comment"=>  {"text"=>"www"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "community_id"=>"dang"}
Community Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "communities".* FROM "communities"  WHERE  "communities"."slug" = 'dang'  ORDER BY "communities"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError for my CommentsController#Create

This basically means you're not permitting the required attributes in your `create` method.

This is what you need:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @comment = @community.comments.new comment_params
      @comment.save
   end

   private

   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:text).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
   end
end
```

You should read up on [`strong params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) to better understand how this works.

---

**Polymorphic**

You also have another issue which can be solved with a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

[image]

Simply, this allows you to associate a model with any number of others.

In your instance, where you can comment on `users` and `communities`, this functionality will serve well:

```
#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sent_comments, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :user_id
   has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

#app/models/community.rb
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

This will allow you to perform the following:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user.comments.new comment_params

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:text).merge(user_id: current_user.id) #-> current_user from Devise
end
```

This allows you to use `@user.comments` and `@community.comments` with a single association.

You'll have to migrate the `commentable_id` & `commentable_type` columns into your `comments` table, but after that the above code should work.